# Multiply an aggregate function SUM with a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to multiply an aggregate function? I need to multiply `SUM(ma.gewight)` for every article (an article is, for example, H114972 which is iron and is 32,1 meters) so the `GROUP BY` groups all same articles and for every different article I need to multiply a different number (the column that I am using to multiply is `e.best_wert` which is the meters, mentioned above). So basically I need to multiply the `SUM(ma.gewicht)` with `e.best_wert` - but it doesn't work.

PS. Gewicht = weight
PSS. e.best_wert = weight value/meters

```
SELECT m.artikel, COUNT(ei.bestell_po) bestell_po_menge, SUM(ma.gewicht) AS summe_gewicht--, SUM(e.best_wert*ma.gewicht) AS summe_kg
FROM MATV030 m
INNER JOIN EINV030 e ON e.BESTELL_NR = m.BESTELL_NR
INNER JOIN EINV035 ei ON e.bestell_nr = ei.bestell_nr 
INNER JOIN MATV010 ma ON m.ARTIKEL = ma.ARTIKEL 
WHERE e.lieferant = '6000176' AND m.menge_buch <> 0 
--AND m.artikel = 'H114972'
AND m.bs = 'WE' AND m.budatum >= '20190101' AND m.budatum < '20190201' 
GROUP BY m.artikel, ma.gewicht
ORDER BY m.artikel ASC
```

Comment: Perhaps `ma.gewicht * SUM(e.best_wert) AS summe_kg`?

Comment: Wait, instead remove ma.gewicht from the GROUP BY. (You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.)

Comment: Remove gewicht from the grouping.

Comment: Sample data will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT m.artikel, COUNT(ei.bestell_po) bestell_po_menge, SUM(ma.gewicht) AS summe_gewicht, (e.best_wert * SUM(ma.gewicht)) AS summe_kg
FROM MATV030 m
INNER JOIN EINV030 e ON e.BESTELL_NR = m.BESTELL_NR
INNER JOIN EINV035 ei ON e.bestell_nr = ei.bestell_nr 
INNER JOIN MATV010 ma ON m.ARTIKEL = ma.ARTIKEL 
WHERE e.lieferant = '6000176' AND m.menge_buch <> 0 
--AND m.artikel = 'H114972'
AND m.bs = 'WE' AND m.budatum >= '20190101' AND m.budatum < '20190201' 
GROUP BY m.artikel, e.best_wert
ORDER BY m.artikel ASC
```

Comment: Nah, it doesnt work as intended- it breaks the GROUP BY clause. But I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you run this query? If yes, please post me the error

Comment: Yes I did, no error message but the multiplied results are wrong - they dont make sense

Comment: This query is correct. The cause for wrong results is probably on your false understanding that all articles have the same `best_wert`. You will either have to ensure all articles have the same `best_wert`, or decide upon an aggregation function (I notice "best" in there; maybe the minimum or maximum?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
;With CTE as
(
SELECT ma.ARTIKEL,  SUM(ma.gewicht) AS summe_gewicht--, SUM(e.best_wert*ma.gewicht) AS summe_kg
FROM MATV030 m
INNER JOIN MATV010 ma ON m.ARTIKEL = ma.ARTIKEL 
WHERE m.menge_buch > 0 
--AND m.artikel = 'H114972'
AND m.bs = 'WE' AND m.budatum >= '20190101' AND m.budatum < '20190201' 
GROUP BY m.ARTIKEL
--ORDER BY m.artikel ASC
)

SELECT m.artikel, COUNT(ei.bestell_po) bestell_po_menge,summe_gewicht, summe_gewicht*e.best_wert AS summe_kg
FROM CTE C
inner join MATV030 m on m.artikel=c.artikel
INNER JOIN EINV030 e ON e.BESTELL_NR = m.BESTELL_NR
INNER JOIN EINV035 ei ON e.bestell_nr = ei.bestell_nr 
WHERE e.lieferant = '6000176' 
GROUP BY m.artikel
ORDER BY m.artikel ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create A CTE (Common Table Expression) table with your aggregate values and then multiply both the tables using CTE.

Comment: Can you provide an example of howto implement CTE? It would add to your answer significantly!